# How do I inherit a method from settings.gradle in build.gradle

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I am new to Gradle and trying to ensure I am not duplicating my code. In my parent module, I am using the same method in both my settings.gradle and build.gradle files respectively. Is there a way I can set up one of the files to inherit the method from the other rather than defining the method in both places?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could place your method in a separate third file (e.g. buildMisc.gradle in subfolder buildfiles/) and apply this from build.gradle like this:

```
apply from: 'buildfiles/buildMisc.gradle'
```

there you could also place common "global" groovy methods to be used in you other tasks, e.g.

```
configure(project.rootProject) {
    ext {
        additionalBuildInfo = { subproject ->
        return [
                operatingSystem: "${System.properties['os.name']} (${System.properties['os.version']})",
                continuousIntegration: System.getenv('CI') ? true: false,
                machine: InetAddress.localHost.hostName,
                // Override buildInfo property time
                time: new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()).format('EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy')
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: I had thought of that, but wanted to avoid creating a third file for one method if I could. It seems that a common file like that though will come in handy later, so I'll do that. Thank you very much!